The values on table are getting multiplied without the intention
I'm making a macro to take the date from a table to another one on the same workbook, but for some reason when it does it the values are multiplied like in the image.

The multiplications aren't uniform. It seems to be multiplying it to have the decimal places being always ".00"
I was expecting to paste the data just like it was on the other table, instead of multiplying it.
I don't know if it's a problem of the macro or a property of table to have the number decimal places to be ".00", but when i do it manually it works just fine...
I would be glad if someone could help me
Edit:
After analyzing the macro i found out that it happens when the macro runs the following code:
Range("L:L").Select
 Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range( _
  "L:L"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
  TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
  Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
  :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

I run that so the data are recognizable by the pivot table i have linked to it.

Please create a [reprex], including all relevant code.

Navigate to File=>Options=>Advanced=>Editing Options and check the setting for Automatically insert a decimal point

Please provide details on the code you attempted, and explain on the specific issues you encountered.

Thank you for the clarification. I added the part of the code that causes the problem.

Is Excel really multiplying those values? Or is it just showing them in another way? (I had the situation where 0.5 became 50 because it was displaying it as a percentage)

@dominique it is indeed multiplying them. To be more acurrate it seems it's removing the comma, but i did not code anything that could do that.
